# Entity Framework: Substituting Primary Columns for Foreign Key Columns

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I've created a new ASP.NET website. I've generated an Entity Data Model from my database and have dropped a entitydatasource and gridview onto my page and wired up the gridview to pull from the entitydatasource. Now I get columns like this:

> id  extension  prefix  did_flag  len  ten_id  restriction_class_id  sfc_id  name_display  building_id  floor  room  phone_id  department_id

In each case where the item is named something_id this reflects a foreign key relationship in the database - and I did choose to have the EDM expose foreign key relationships. I'd like to make it so the gridview pulls in the values for these foreign keys rather than just showing the ID numbers - so, for example, department_id might have a value of "101" right now but it should pull from the department table "Marketing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember how I ever made it do this in the first place, but the natural action is to display the values - Dynamic Data handles this automatically, one does not have to tell it to do this.